# How to populate Picker with languages in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of all languages. I want to populate picker with all the languages but I get an error msg.

This is my code. It looks like the offending code is `{this.state.isoLangs.map((item, index) => {
                                return <Picker.Item key={index} label={item.name} value={item.nativeName} />
                            })}`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, Picker, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableHighlight, View} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import {Constants} from 'expo';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.section1}>
                    <Text style={[styles.text, {paddingBottom: 20}]}>{'Welcome'}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section2}>
                    <Text style={[styles.text, {paddingTop: 20}]}>{'Your verification was successful'}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section3}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{'Sign up as:'}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section4}>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

                        <View style={styles.button}>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>

                                <Image source={require('./assets/stck2.png')} style={styles.image}/>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>

                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{'Translator'}</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>

                        </View>


                        <View style={styles.button}>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Recruiter')}>

                            <Image source={require('./assets/stck1.png')} style={styles.image}/>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Recruiter')}>

                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{'Recruiter'}</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {user: '',

        isoLangs : {
            "ab":{
                "name":"Abkhaz",
                "nativeName":"аҧсуа"
            },
            "aa":{
                "name":"Afar",
                "nativeName":"Afaraf"
            },
            "af":{
                "name":"Afrikaans",
                "nativeName":"Afrikaans"
            },
            "ak":{
                "name":"Akan",
                "nativeName":"Akan"
            },
            "sq":{
                "name":"Albanian",
                "nativeName":"Shqip"
            },
            "am":{
                "name":"Amharic",
                "nativeName":"አማርኛ"
            },
            "ar":{
                "name":"Arabic",
                "nativeName":"العربية"
            },
            "an":{
                "name":"Aragonese",
                "nativeName":"Aragonés"
            },
            "hy":{
                "name":"Armenian",
                "nativeName":"Հայերեն"
            },
            "as":{
                "name":"Assamese",
                "nativeName":"অসমীয়া"
            },
            "av":{
                "name":"Avaric",
                "nativeName":"авар мацӀ, магӀарул мацӀ"
            },
            "ae":{
                "name":"Avestan",
                "nativeName":"avesta"
            },
            "ay":{
                "name":"Aymara",
                "nativeName":"aymar aru"
            },
            "az":{
                "name":"Azerbaijani",
                "nativeName":"azərbaycan dili"
            },
            "bm":{
                "name":"Bambara",
                "nativeName":"bamanankan"
            },
            "ba":{
                "name":"Bashkir",
                "nativeName":"башҡорт теле"
            },
            "eu":{
                "name":"Basque",
                "nativeName":"euskara, euskera"
            },
            "be":{
                "name":"Belarusian",
                "nativeName":"Беларуская"
            },
            "bn":{
                "name":"Bengali",
                "nativeName":"বাংলা"
            },
            "bh":{
                "name":"Bihari",
                "nativeName":"भोजपुरी"
            },
            "bi":{
                "name":"Bislama",
                "nativeName":"Bislama"
            },
            "bs":{
                "name":"Bosnian",
                "nativeName":"bosanski jezik"
            },
            "br":{
                "name":"Breton",
                "nativeName":"brezhoneg"
            },
            "bg":{
                "name":"Bulgarian",
                "nativeName":"български език"
            },
            "my":{
                "name":"Burmese",
                "nativeName":"ဗမာစာ"
            },
            "ca":{
                "name":"Catalan; Valencian",
                "nativeName":"Català"
            },
            "ch":{
                "name":"Chamorro",
                "nativeName":"Chamoru"
            },
            "ce":{
                "name":"Chechen",
                "nativeName":"нохчийн мотт"
            },
            "ny":{
                "name":"Chichewa; Chewa; Nyanja",
                "nativeName":"chiCheŵa, chinyanja"
            },
            "zh":{
                "name":"Chinese",
                "nativeName":"中文 (Zhōngwén), 汉语, 漢語"
            },
            "cv":{
                "name":"Chuvash",
                "nativeName":"чӑваш чӗлхи"
            },
            "kw":{
                "name":"Cornish",
                "nativeName":"Kernewek"
            },
            "co":{
                "name":"Corsican",
                "nativeName":"corsu, lingua corsa"
            },
            "cr":{
                "name":"Cree",
                "nativeName":"ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐍᐏᐣ"
            },
            "hr":{
                "name":"Croatian",
                "nativeName":"hrvatski"
            },
            "cs":{
                "name":"Czech",
                "nativeName":"česky, čeština"
            },
            "da":{
                "name":"Danish",
                "nativeName":"dansk"
            },
            "dv":{
                "name":"Divehi; Dhivehi; Maldivian;",
                "nativeName":"ދިވެހި"
            },
            "nl":{
                "name":"Dutch",
                "nativeName":"Nederlands, Vlaams"
            },
            "en":{
                "name":"English",
                "nativeName":"English"
            },
            "eo":{
                "name":"Esperanto",
                "nativeName":"Esperanto"
            },
            "et":{
                "name":"Estonian",
                "nativeName":"eesti, eesti keel"
            },
            "ee":{
                "name":"Ewe",
                "nativeName":"Eʋegbe"
            },
            "fo":{
                "name":"Faroese",
                "nativeName":"føroyskt"
            },
            "fj":{
                "name":"Fijian",
                "nativeName":"vosa Vakaviti"
            },
            "fi":{
                "name":"Finnish",
                "nativeName":"suomi, suomen kieli"
            },
            "fr":{
                "name":"French",
                "nativeName":"français, langue française"
            },
            "ff":{
                "name":"Fula; Fulah; Pulaar; Pular",
                "nativeName":"Fulfulde, Pulaar, Pular"
            },
            "gl":{
                "name":"Galician",
                "nativeName":"Galego"
            },
            "ka":{
                "name":"Georgian",
                "nativeName":"ქართული"
            },
            "de":{
                "name":"German",
                "nativeName":"Deutsch"
            },
            "el":{
                "name":"Greek, Modern",
                "nativeName":"Ελληνικά"
            },
            "gn":{
                "name":"Guaraní",
                "nativeName":"Avañeẽ"
            },
            "gu":{
                "name":"Gujarati",
                "nativeName":"ગુજરાતી"
            },
            "ht":{
                "name":"Haitian; Haitian Creole",
                "nativeName":"Kreyòl ayisyen"
            },
            "ha":{
                "name":"Hausa",
                "nativeName":"Hausa, هَوُسَ"
            },
            "he":{
                "name":"Hebrew (modern)",
                "nativeName":"עברית"
            },
            "hz":{
                "name":"Herero",
                "nativeName":"Otjiherero"
            },
            "hi":{
                "name":"Hindi",
                "nativeName":"हिन्दी, हिंदी"
            },
            "ho":{
                "name":"Hiri Motu",
                "nativeName":"Hiri Motu"
            },
            "hu":{
                "name":"Hungarian",
                "nativeName":"Magyar"
            },
            "ia":{
                "name":"Interlingua",
                "nativeName":"Interlingua"
            },
            "id":{
                "name":"Indonesian",
                "nativeName":"Bahasa Indonesia"
            },
            "ie":{
                "name":"Interlingue",
                "nativeName":"Originally called Occidental; then Interlingue after WWII"
            },
            "ga":{
                "name":"Irish",
                "nativeName":"Gaeilge"
            },
            ...
            "yi":{
                "name":"Yiddish",
                "nativeName":"ייִדיש"
            },
            "yo":{
                "name":"Yoruba",
                "nativeName":"Yorùbá"
            },
            "za":{
                "name":"Zhuang, Chuang",
                "nativeName":"Saɯ cueŋƅ, Saw cuengh"
            }
        }};

        getLanguageName = function(key) {
            key = key.slice(0,2);
            lang = this.state.isoLangs[key];
            return lang ? lang.name : undefined;
        };
        getLanguageNativeName = function(key) {
            key = key.slice(0,2);
            lang = this.state.isoLangs[key];
            return lang ? lang.nativeName : undefined;
        };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'normal',
                        color: 'skyblue',
                    }}>
                        Which languages do you translate?
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Picker style={{width: 150}}
                            selectedValue={this.state.language}
                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
                        <Picker.Item label={this.getLanguageName('sv')} value="java"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js"/>


                            {this.state.isoLangs.map((item, index) => {
                                return <Picker.Item key={index} label={item.name} value={item.nativeName} />
                            })}



                    </Picker>
                    <Image
                        source={require('./assets/Arrow.png')}
                    />

                    <Picker style={{width: 150}}
                            selectedValue={this.state.language}
                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
                        <Picker.Item label="Arabic" value="java"/>
                        <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js"/>
                    </Picker>
                </View>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'normal',
                        color: 'skyblue',
                    }}>+ add language</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3')}>
                        <Image
                            source={require('./assets/Next.png')}

                        />
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
        },
        Details: {
            screen: DetailsScreen,
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <RootStack/>;
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    section1: {
        flex: 0.17,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    section2: {
        flex: 0.30,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    section3: {
        flex: 0.10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    section4: {
        flex: 0.43
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 24,
        color: '#53a6db',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingTop: 40,
        paddingBottom: 40,
        paddingLeft: 40,
        paddingRight: 40
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    button: {
        flex: 0.5,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 24,
        color: '#53a6db',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        paddingLeft: 5,
        paddingRight: 5
    },
    image: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    }
});
```

The error message is:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.state.isoLangs.map')

This error is located at:
    in DetailsScreen (at SceneView.js:17)
    in SceneView (at CardStack.js:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at CardStack.js:454)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at CardStack.js:453)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:147)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.js:12)
    in Card (at PointerEventsContainer.js:39)
    in Container (at CardStack.js:498)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at CardStack.js:414)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at CardStack.js:413)
    in CardStack (at CardStackTransitioner.js:67)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at Transitioner.js:142)
    in Transitioner (at CardStackTransitioner.js:19)
    in CardStackTransitioner (at StackNavigator.js:41)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:226)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:875)
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
* App.js:811:16 in render
- node_modules\react-proxy\modules\createPrototypeProxy.js:44:35 in proxiedMethod
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7866:21 in finishClassComponent
- ... 18 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: Please add the error message you get to the question.

Comment: `map` can only be used on arrays. `this.state.isoLangs` is not an array.

Comment: @bennygenel How should I proceed if I want the languages as items in a Picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through languages you can use below example. For more info you can check [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

**Example**

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.language}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
          {
            Object.keys(this.state.isoLangs).map((lang) => {
              console.log('lang: ', lang);
              console.log('lang name: ', this.state.isoLangs[lang].name);
              console.log('lang nativeName: ', this.state.isoLangs[lang].nativeName);
              return  <Picker.Item key={lang} label={this.state.isoLangs[lang].name} value={lang} />
            })
          }
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

IsoLangs need to be an array, try this ...

```
isoLangs : [
            "ab":{
                "name":"Abkhaz",
                "nativeName":"аҧсуа"
            },
            "aa":{
                "name":"Afar",
                "nativeName":"Afaraf"
            },
            "af":{
                "name":"Afrikaans",
                "nativeName":"Afrikaans"
            },
            "ak":{
                "name":"Akan",
                "nativeName":"Akan"
            },
            "sq":{
                "name":"Albanian",
                "nativeName":"Shqip"
            },
            "am":{
                "name":"Amharic",
                "nativeName":"አማርኛ"
            },
            "ar":{
                "name":"Arabic",
                "nativeName":"العربية"
            },
            "an":{
                "name":"Aragonese",
                "nativeName":"Aragonés"
            },
            "hy":{
                "name":"Armenian",
                "nativeName":"Հայերեն"
            },
            "as":{
                "name":"Assamese",
                "nativeName":"অসমীয়া"
            },
            "av":{
                "name":"Avaric",
                "nativeName":"авар мацӀ, магӀарул мацӀ"
            },
            "ae":{
                "name":"Avestan",
                "nativeName":"avesta"
            },
            "ay":{
                "name":"Aymara",
                "nativeName":"aymar aru"
            },
            "az":{
                "name":"Azerbaijani",
                "nativeName":"azərbaycan dili"
            },
            "bm":{
                "name":"Bambara",
                "nativeName":"bamanankan"
            },
            "ba":{
                "name":"Bashkir",
                "nativeName":"башҡорт теле"
            },
            "eu":{
                "name":"Basque",
                "nativeName":"euskara, euskera"
            },
            "be":{
                "name":"Belarusian",
                "nativeName":"Беларуская"
            },
            "bn":{
                "name":"Bengali",
                "nativeName":"বাংলা"
            },
            "bh":{
                "name":"Bihari",
                "nativeName":"भोजपुरी"
            },
            "bi":{
                "name":"Bislama",
                "nativeName":"Bislama"
            },
            "bs":{
                "name":"Bosnian",
                "nativeName":"bosanski jezik"
            },
            "br":{
                "name":"Breton",
                "nativeName":"brezhoneg"
            },
            "bg":{
                "name":"Bulgarian",
                "nativeName":"български език"
            },
            "my":{
                "name":"Burmese",
                "nativeName":"ဗမာစာ"
            },
            "ca":{
                "name":"Catalan; Valencian",
                "nativeName":"Català"
            },
            "ch":{
                "name":"Chamorro",
                "nativeName":"Chamoru"
            },
            "ce":{
                "name":"Chechen",
                "nativeName":"нохчийн мотт"
            },
            "ny":{
                "name":"Chichewa; Chewa; Nyanja",
                "nativeName":"chiCheŵa, chinyanja"
            },
            "zh":{
                "name":"Chinese",
                "nativeName":"中文 (Zhōngwén), 汉语, 漢語"
            },
            "cv":{
                "name":"Chuvash",
                "nativeName":"чӑваш чӗлхи"
            },
            "kw":{
                "name":"Cornish",
                "nativeName":"Kernewek"
            },
            "co":{
                "name":"Corsican",
                "nativeName":"corsu, lingua corsa"
            },
            "cr":{
                "name":"Cree",
                "nativeName":"ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐍᐏᐣ"
            },
            "hr":{
                "name":"Croatian",
                "nativeName":"hrvatski"
            },
            "cs":{
                "name":"Czech",
                "nativeName":"česky, čeština"
            },
            "da":{
                "name":"Danish",
                "nativeName":"dansk"
            },
            "dv":{
                "name":"Divehi; Dhivehi; Maldivian;",
                "nativeName":"ދިވެހި"
            },
            "nl":{
                "name":"Dutch",
                "nativeName":"Nederlands, Vlaams"
            },
            "en":{
                "name":"English",
                "nativeName":"English"
            },
            "eo":{
                "name":"Esperanto",
                "nativeName":"Esperanto"
            },
            "et":{
                "name":"Estonian",
                "nativeName":"eesti, eesti keel"
            },
            "ee":{
                "name":"Ewe",
                "nativeName":"Eʋegbe"
            },
            "fo":{
                "name":"Faroese",
                "nativeName":"føroyskt"
            },
            "fj":{
                "name":"Fijian",
                "nativeName":"vosa Vakaviti"
            },
            "fi":{
                "name":"Finnish",
                "nativeName":"suomi, suomen kieli"
            },
            "fr":{
                "name":"French",
                "nativeName":"français, langue française"
            },
            "ff":{
                "name":"Fula; Fulah; Pulaar; Pular",
                "nativeName":"Fulfulde, Pulaar, Pular"
            },
            "gl":{
                "name":"Galician",
                "nativeName":"Galego"
            },
            "ka":{
                "name":"Georgian",
                "nativeName":"ქართული"
            },
            "de":{
                "name":"German",
                "nativeName":"Deutsch"
            },
            "el":{
                "name":"Greek, Modern",
                "nativeName":"Ελληνικά"
            },
            "gn":{
                "name":"Guaraní",
                "nativeName":"Avañeẽ"
            },
            "gu":{
                "name":"Gujarati",
                "nativeName":"ગુજરાતી"
            },
            "ht":{
                "name":"Haitian; Haitian Creole",
                "nativeName":"Kreyòl ayisyen"
            },
            "ha":{
                "name":"Hausa",
                "nativeName":"Hausa, هَوُسَ"
            },
            "he":{
                "name":"Hebrew (modern)",
                "nativeName":"עברית"
            },
            "hz":{
                "name":"Herero",
                "nativeName":"Otjiherero"
            },
            "hi":{
                "name":"Hindi",
                "nativeName":"हिन्दी, हिंदी"
            },
            "ho":{
                "name":"Hiri Motu",
                "nativeName":"Hiri Motu"
            },
            "hu":{
                "name":"Hungarian",
                "nativeName":"Magyar"
            },
            "ia":{
                "name":"Interlingua",
                "nativeName":"Interlingua"
            },
            "id":{
                "name":"Indonesian",
                "nativeName":"Bahasa Indonesia"
            },
            "ie":{
                "name":"Interlingue",
                "nativeName":"Originally called Occidental; then Interlingue after WWII"
            },
            "ga":{
                "name":"Irish",
                "nativeName":"Gaeilge"
            },
            ...
            "yi":{
                "name":"Yiddish",
                "nativeName":"ייִדיש"
            },
            "yo":{
                "name":"Yoruba",
                "nativeName":"Yorùbá"
            },
            "za":{
                "name":"Zhuang, Chuang",
                "nativeName":"Saɯ cueŋƅ, Saw cuengh"
            }
        ];
```